# How to change Apache Zeppelin configurations on EMR EC2 cluster to show helium packages?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I'm not sure how to change apache zeppelin configurations on a EMR cluster. The idea is to change `zeppelin.helium.registry` value to `helium,https://s3.amazonaws.com/helium-package/helium.json` in order for helium to work (https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/development/helium/overview.html).

[image]

I use the 0.10.0 zeppelin version and Helium looks like this:
[image]

How can I change the zeppelin configs, so that Helium uses the correct registry?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following configuration helped me -

| Classification | Property | Value | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| zeppelin-site | zeppelin.helium.registry | helium,https://s3.amazonaws.com/helium-package/helium.json | Cluster configuration |

[image]